# Jquery Dynatree , only the child node is selectable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have a dynatree with multiple parent and child nodes.I am getting the json data and passing to the dynatree to form a tree structure.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#tree").dynatree({
                checkbox: true,
                classNames: {checkbox: "dynatree-radio"},
                hasChildren:true,
                selectMode: 1,
                onDblClick: function(node, event) {
                    node.toggleSelect();
                },
                onKeydown: function(node, event) {
                    if( event.which == 32 ) {
                    node.toggleSelect();
                    return false;
                    }
                },
      <%=codesJSON%>
            });
    });
```

The nodes can be selected using a radio button.
[image]
i would like to select only the child node when the tree is fully loaded and the parent node is just for visibility.I have tried using the unselectable property but it doesn't seem to be working for my case.

Is there a way to achieve this.

Kindly help thanks...

Set up a jsfiddle for it - http://jsfiddle.net/jegadeesb/zRPfx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the node definition set the option `isFolder: true` and `unselectable : true`

ex

```
$(function() {
    // Variant 1:
    $("span.dynatree-edit-icon").live("click", function(e) {
        alert("Edit " + $.ui.dynatree.getNode(e.target));
    });
    $("#tree").dynatree({
        checkbox : true,
        classNames : {
            checkbox : "dynatree-radio"
        },
        onActivate : function(node) {
            // $("#info").text("You activated " + node);
        },
        onRender : function(node, nodeSpan) {
            $(nodeSpan)
            .find('.dynatree-icon')
            .before('<span class="dynatree-icon dynatree-edit-icon"></span>');
        },
        // Variant 2:
        onClick : function(node, e) {
            if ($(e.target).hasClass("dynatree-edit-icon")) {
                $("#info").text("You clicked " + node + ",  url=" + node.url);
            }
        },
        children : [{
            title : "Item 1"
        }, {
            title : "Folder 2",
            isFolder : true,
            unselectable : true,
            children : [{
                title : "Sub-item 2.1"
            }, {
                title : "Sub-item 2.2"
            }]
        }, {
            title : "Item 3"
        }]
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HLTL5/)

From [the doc](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h4.2.1)

> isFolder: false, // Use a folder icon. Also the node is expandable but
> not selectable.
>
> unselectable: false, // Prevent selection.

Comment: @ Arun i tried your example .My requirement is to select only the child nodes and not the parent node.By setting the isFolder to false , doesnt seem to satisfy my requirement.

Comment: @jegadees it should be set to true for the parent elements

Comment: I have setup a jsfiddle for it.http://jsfiddle.net/jegadeesb/zRPfx/ Kindly help to take a look.